# How to move to top of page on error using jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate and trying to move (or scroll) to the top of the page when an error is found. I've added the [focusInvalid option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to stop focusing on a field with an error, but can't figure out how to move to the top of the page (as at the top of the page, my error container is visible).

A simplified version of my script is below, and thanks for any help with this.

```
$(".event-form").validate({
  errorContainer: ".error-container",
  errorLabelContainer: ".error-container ul",
  wrapper: "li",
  focusInvalid: false,
  ignore: "",
  rules: {
    title: { required: true }
  },
  messages: {
    title: "You must enter the title"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".event-form").validate({
 errorContainer: ".error-container",
  errorLabelContainer: ".error-container ul",
  wrapper: "li",
  focusInvalid: false,
  ignore: "",
  rules: {
    title: { required: true }
  },
  messages: {
    title: "You must enter the title"
  },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
              $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
        }
    }
})
```